# YouTube thumbnail is blurry when using cueVideo

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

When I try to load a video from JS, the thumbnail shows up as blurry for some reason. But when I just paste in the iframe embed code the thumbnail renders fine.

**Example:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBvVZG

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot]

It looks like the youtube js api is loading in the `default.jpg` screenshot, while embedding an iframe loads in `sddefault.jpg`

The video being rendered is the HTML5 video. Tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari on OSX 10.10 on MBP (Retina)

P.S. Yes, I need to load in the first video in JS, I can't do it in the HTML as the video ID's are being fetched from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code to this which seems to load the `sddefault` thumbnail (in fact, it would load any other thumbnail depending on player size):

```
var video;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  video = new YT.Player('video', {
    videoId: '1nBwfZZvjKo' // From the manual: the YouTube video ID that
                           // identifies the video that the player will load.
  });
}
```

[**Updated Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPPKJY) and [**another pen with larger player**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emmOoo)